# Mapping entire cartesian plane to a line with 2x2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a homework question that I have been staring at helplessly for far too long, and if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.
Matrix A = \begin{bmatrix}
       a & b \\
       c & d
   \end{bmatrix}
This matrix maps all points on the Cartesian plane to a line L that is parallel to a vector t and passes through the origin. The question is to write the equation that defines relationship between the variables a, b, c, d and some scalar s. A hint was given to consider the vectors (1,0) and (0,1), but I'm still really not sure how to even start this. Any advice?

Comment: Try to think about whether the matrix is invertible. What does that tell you?

Comment: You might recall that the range of a linear transformation given by a matrix is the column space of that matrix. You want that range to be the span of a single vector. Does this point you in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

The points on the line have the form $\alpha t$, for all scalars $\alpha$. Thus you must have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\alpha_1 t
$$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\alpha_2 t
$$
If
$$
t=\begin{bmatrix}t_1\\t_2\end{bmatrix}
$$
this becomes
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a\\c\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1 t_1\\ \alpha_1 t_2\end{bmatrix},
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}b\\d\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_2 t_1\\ \alpha_2 t_2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
At least one among $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ should be nonzero.